# ASN1 out of memory. during a signedCMS.decode

Tags: c#, security

I am having a problem using the signedCMS.decode routine. See the code below.

The error seems to occur when the file size is too big in this case 11MB.

```
private static void RemoveZfoSignature(string zfoFileName)
{
    byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(zfoFileName);
    var contentInfo = new ContentInfo(fileContents);
    var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo);

    // This line throws the error 100% of the time
    signedCms.Decode(fileContents);

    signedCms.RemoveSignature(0);
    byte[] outfile = signedCms.ContentInfo.Content;
    string outFileName = zfoFileName.Replace(".zfo", "_tmp.zfo");
    File.WriteAllBytes(outFileName, outfile);
}
```

Here is the exact error:

```
"System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: ASN1 out of memory.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.OpenToDecode(Byte[] encodedMessage, ContentInfo contentInfo, Boolean detached)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.Decode(Byte[] encodedMessage)
   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.RemoveZfoSignature(String zfoFileName) in C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication2\\ConsoleApplication2\\Program.cs:line 30"
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

I've updated the code now to look like this, but now its failing on the removeSignature saying The CMS Message is not signed.

```
/// <summary>
/// Removes the ZFO signature from the ZFO, so that it is possible to extract attachments.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="zfoFileName">
/// The zfo file name.
/// </param>
private static void RemoveZfoSignature(string zfoFileName)
    {
        string outFileName = zfoFileName.Replace(".zfo", "_tmp.zfo"); 
        FileStream inFile = null;
        FileStream outFile = null;
        inFile = File.Open(zfoFileName, FileMode.Open);
        outFile = File.Create(outFileName);
        LargeCMS.CMS cms = new LargeCMS.CMS(); 
        cms.Decode(inFile, outFile);

        // Clean up
        if (inFile != null) { inFile.Close(); }
        if (outFile != null) { outFile.Close(); }

        byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(outFileName);
        var contentInfo = new ContentInfo(fileContents);
        var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo);
        //signedCms.Decode(fileContents);
        signedCms.RemoveSignature(0);
        byte[] outfileContent = signedCms.ContentInfo.Content;

        File.WriteAllBytes(outFileName, outfileContent);
    }
```

Comment: Also seems to only be happening on windows 7 systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this page](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/cryptdecryptmessage-fails-returning-an-crypt-e-asn1-memory-error-value.aspx):

> There is a counter in the ASN structure that is increased every time an octet block is processed when the ASN sequence that wraps the octets is BER encoded.  It adds the number of bytes that have already been processed plus the new block size; as the number of processed bytes grows that is added to the counter and the rate at which the counter grows increases. Since the counter is represented by an integer it can overflow.  On Windows 7, the ASN code checks for overflow so the function fails.  On pre-Windows 7 platforms, the overflow still occurs but it wasn't checked.  That counter is not critical for operation and did not cause issues in the code for the previous versions of the OS.

The only resolution seems to be calling the native, lower level functions listed on that page.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2010/04/09/how-to-call-cryptmsg-api-in-streaming-mode-c.aspx) for an example.

All the following code comes from that page (duplicated here in case that page ever goes down):

File form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.IO;

namespace LargeCMS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            subjectTextBox.Text = "ALEX";
            originalTextBox.Text = "my1GBfile.txt";
            encodedTextBox.Text = "encodeddata.p7s";
            decodedTextBox.Text = "decodeddata.txt";
        }

        private void encodeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Variables
            X509Store store = null;
            X509Certificate2 cert = null;
            FileStream inFile = null;
            FileStream outFile = null;
            CMS cms = null;

            try
            {
                // Get user cert
                store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
                cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subjectTextBox.Text, true)[0];

                // Open file with data to encode
                inFile = File.Open(originalTextBox.Text, FileMode.Open);

                // Create file for encoded data
                outFile = File.Create(encodedTextBox.Text);

                // Encode data
                cms = new CMS();
                cms.Encode(cert, inFile, outFile);

                MessageBox.Show("Sucess!!!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Show errors
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clean up
                if (store != null) { store.Close(); }
                if (inFile != null) { inFile.Close(); }
                if (outFile != null) { outFile.Close(); }
            }
        }

        private void decodeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Variables
            FileStream inFile = null;
            FileStream outFile = null;
            CMS cms = null;

            try
            {
                // Open file with data to decode
                inFile = File.Open(encodedTextBox.Text, FileMode.Open);

                // Create file for encoded data
                outFile = File.Create(decodedTextBox.Text);

                // Decode data
                cms = new CMS();
                cms.Decode(inFile, outFile);

                MessageBox.Show("Sucess!!!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clean up
                if (inFile != null) { inFile.Close(); }
                if (outFile != null) { outFile.Close(); }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

File cms.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace LargeCMS
{
    class CMS
    {
        // File stream to use in callback function
        private FileStream m_callbackFile;

        // Streaming callback function for encoding
        private Boolean StreamOutputCallback(IntPtr pvArg, IntPtr pbData, int cbData, Boolean fFinal)
        {
            // Write all bytes to encoded file
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[cbData];
            Marshal.Copy(pbData, bytes, 0, cbData);
            m_callbackFile.Write(bytes, 0, cbData);

            if (fFinal)
            {
                // This is the last piece. Close the file
                m_callbackFile.Flush();
                m_callbackFile.Close();
                m_callbackFile = null;
            }

            return true;
        }

        // Encode CMS with streaming to support large data
        public void Encode(X509Certificate2 cert, FileStream inFile, FileStream outFile)
        {
            // Variables
            Win32.CMSG_SIGNER_ENCODE_INFO SignerInfo;
            Win32.CMSG_SIGNED_ENCODE_INFO SignedInfo;
            Win32.CMSG_STREAM_INFO StreamInfo;
            Win32.CERT_CONTEXT[] CertContexts = null;
            Win32.BLOB[] CertBlobs;

            X509Chain chain = null;
            X509ChainElement[] chainElements = null;
            X509Certificate2[] certs = null;
            RSACryptoServiceProvider key = null;
            BinaryReader stream = null;
            GCHandle gchandle = new GCHandle();

            IntPtr hProv = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr SignerInfoPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr CertBlobsPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr hMsg = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr pbPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            Byte[] pbData;
            int dwFileSize;
            int dwRemaining;
            int dwSize;
            Boolean bResult = false;

            try
            {
                // Get data to encode
                dwFileSize = (int)inFile.Length;
                stream = new BinaryReader(inFile);
                pbData = stream.ReadBytes(dwFileSize);

                // Prepare stream for encoded info
                m_callbackFile = outFile;

                // Get cert chain
                chain = new X509Chain();
                chain.Build(cert);
                chainElements = new X509ChainElement[chain.ChainElements.Count];
                chain.ChainElements.CopyTo(chainElements, 0);

                // Get certs in chain
                certs = new X509Certificate2[chainElements.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < chainElements.Length; i++)
                {
                    certs[i] = chainElements[i].Certificate;
                }

                // Get context of all certs in chain
                CertContexts = new Win32.CERT_CONTEXT[certs.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < certs.Length; i++)
                {
                    CertContexts[i] = (Win32.CERT_CONTEXT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(certs[i].Handle, typeof(Win32.CERT_CONTEXT));
                }

                // Get cert blob of all certs
                CertBlobs = new Win32.BLOB[CertContexts.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < CertContexts.Length; i++)
                {
                    CertBlobs[i].cbData = CertContexts[i].cbCertEncoded;
                    CertBlobs[i].pbData = CertContexts[i].pbCertEncoded;
                }

                // Get CSP of client certificate
                key = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certs[0].PrivateKey;

                bResult = Win32.CryptAcquireContext(
                    ref hProv,
                    key.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName,
                    key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName,
                    key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType,
                    0
                );
                if (!bResult)
                {
                    throw new Exception("CryptAcquireContext error #" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(), new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }

                // Populate Signer Info struct
                SignerInfo = new Win32.CMSG_SIGNER_ENCODE_INFO();
                SignerInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(SignerInfo);
                SignerInfo.pCertInfo = CertContexts[0].pCertInfo;
                SignerInfo.hCryptProvOrhNCryptKey = hProv;
                SignerInfo.dwKeySpec = (int)key.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyNumber;
                SignerInfo.HashAlgorithm.pszObjId = Win32.szOID_OIWSEC_sha1;

                // Populate Signed Info struct
                SignedInfo = new Win32.CMSG_SIGNED_ENCODE_INFO();
                SignedInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(SignedInfo);

                SignedInfo.cSigners = 1;
                SignerInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(SignerInfo));
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(SignerInfo, SignerInfoPtr, false);
                SignedInfo.rgSigners = SignerInfoPtr;

                SignedInfo.cCertEncoded = CertBlobs.Length;
                CertBlobsPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(CertBlobs[0]) * CertBlobs.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < CertBlobs.Length; i++)
                {
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(CertBlobs[i], new IntPtr(CertBlobsPtr.ToInt64() + (Marshal.SizeOf(CertBlobs[i]) * i)), false);
                }               
                SignedInfo.rgCertEncoded = CertBlobsPtr;

                // Populate Stream Info struct
                StreamInfo = new Win32.CMSG_STREAM_INFO();
                StreamInfo.cbContent = dwFileSize;
                StreamInfo.pfnStreamOutput = new Win32.StreamOutputCallbackDelegate(StreamOutputCallback);

                // TODO: CMSG_DETACHED_FLAG

                // Open message to encode
                hMsg = Win32.CryptMsgOpenToEncode(
                    Win32.X509_ASN_ENCODING | Win32.PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
                    0,
                    Win32.CMSG_SIGNED,
                    ref SignedInfo,
                    null,
                    ref StreamInfo
                );
                if (hMsg.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    throw new Exception("CryptMsgOpenToEncode error #" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(), new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }

                // Process the whole message
                gchandle = GCHandle.Alloc(pbData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                pbPtr = gchandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
                dwRemaining = dwFileSize;
                dwSize = (dwFileSize < 1024 * 1000 * 100) ? dwFileSize : 1024 * 1000 * 100;
                while (dwRemaining > 0)
                {
                    // Update message piece by piece     
                    bResult = Win32.CryptMsgUpdate(
                        hMsg,
                        pbPtr,
                        dwSize,
                        (dwRemaining <= dwSize) ? true : false
                    );
                    if (!bResult)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("CryptMsgUpdate error #" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(), new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                    }

                    // Move to the next piece
                    pbPtr = new IntPtr(pbPtr.ToInt64() + dwSize);
                    dwRemaining -= dwSize;
                    if (dwRemaining < dwSize)
                    {
                        dwSize = dwRemaining;
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clean up
                if (gchandle.IsAllocated)
                {
                    gchandle.Free();
                }
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    stream.Close();
                }
                if (m_callbackFile != null)
                {
                    m_callbackFile.Close();
                }
                if (!CertBlobsPtr.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(CertBlobsPtr);
                }

                if (!SignerInfoPtr.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(SignerInfoPtr);
                }
                if (!hProv.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    Win32.CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
                }
                if (!hMsg.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    Win32.CryptMsgClose(hMsg);
                }
            }
        }

        // Decode CMS with streaming to support large data
        public void Decode(FileStream inFile, FileStream outFile)
        {
            // Variables
            Win32.CMSG_STREAM_INFO StreamInfo;
            Win32.CERT_CONTEXT SignerCertContext;

            BinaryReader stream = null;
            GCHandle gchandle = new GCHandle();

            IntPtr hMsg = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr pSignerCertInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr pSignerCertContext = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr pbPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr hStore = IntPtr.Zero;
            Byte[] pbData;
            Boolean bResult = false;
            int dwFileSize;
            int dwRemaining;
            int dwSize;
            int cbSignerCertInfo;

            try
            {
                // Get data to decode
                dwFileSize = (int)inFile.Length;
                stream = new BinaryReader(inFile);
                pbData = stream.ReadBytes(dwFileSize);

                // Prepare stream for decoded info
                m_callbackFile = outFile;

                // Populate Stream Info struct
                StreamInfo = new Win32.CMSG_STREAM_INFO();
                StreamInfo.cbContent = dwFileSize;
                StreamInfo.pfnStreamOutput = new Win32.StreamOutputCallbackDelegate(StreamOutputCallback);

                // Open message to decode
                hMsg = Win32.CryptMsgOpenToDecode(
                    Win32.X509_ASN_ENCODING | Win32.PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
                    0,
                    0,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    ref StreamInfo
                );
                if (hMsg.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    throw new Exception("CryptMsgOpenToDecode error #" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(), new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }

                // Process the whole message
                gchandle = GCHandle.Alloc(pbData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                pbPtr = gchandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
                dwRemaining = dwFileSize;
                dwSize = (dwFileSize < 1024 * 1000 * 100) ?  dwFileSize : 1024 * 1000 * 100;
                while (dwRemaining > 0)
                {
                    // Update message piece by piece     
                    bResult = Win32.CryptMsgUpdate(
                        hMsg,
                        pbPtr,
                        dwSize,
                        (dwRemaining <= dwSize) ? true : false
                    );
                    if (!bResult)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("CryptMsgUpdate error #" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(), new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                    }

                    // Move to the next piece
                    pbPtr = new IntPtr(pbPtr.ToInt64() + dwSize);
                    dwRemaining -= dwSize;
                    if (dwRemaining < dwSize)
                    {
                        dwSize = dwRemaining;
                    }
                }

                // Get signer certificate info
                cbSignerCertInfo = 0;
                bResult = Win32.CryptMsgGetParam(
                    hMsg,
                    Win32.CMSG_SIGNER_CERT_INFO_PARAM,
                    0,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    ref cbSignerCertInfo
                );
                if (!bResult)
                {
                    throw new Exception("CryptMsgGetParam error #" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(), new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }

                pSignerCertInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(cbSignerCertInfo);

                bResult = Win32.CryptMsgGetParam(
                    hMsg,
                    Win32.CMSG_SIGNER_CERT_INFO_PARAM,
                    0,
                    pSignerCertInfo,
                    ref cbSignerCertInfo
                );
                if (!bResult)
                {
                    throw new Exception("CryptMsgGetParam error #" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(), new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }

                // Open a cert store in memory with the certs from the message
                hStore = Win32.CertOpenStore(
                    Win32.CERT_STORE_PROV_MSG,
                    Win32.X509_ASN_ENCODING | Win32.PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    0,
                    hMsg
                );
                if (hStore.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    throw new Exception("CertOpenStore error #" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(), new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }

                // Find the signer's cert in the store
                pSignerCertContext = Win32.CertGetSubjectCertificateFromStore(
                    hStore,
                    Win32.X509_ASN_ENCODING | Win32.PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
                    pSignerCertInfo
                );
                if (pSignerCertContext.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    throw new Exception("CertGetSubjectCertificateFromStore error #" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(), new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }

                // Set message for verifying
                SignerCertContext = (Win32.CERT_CONTEXT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pSignerCertContext, typeof(Win32.CERT_CONTEXT));                
                bResult = Win32.CryptMsgControl(
                    hMsg, 
                    0, 
                    Win32.CMSG_CTRL_VERIFY_SIGNATURE,
                    SignerCertContext.pCertInfo
                );
                if (!bResult)
                {
                    throw new Exception("CryptMsgControl error #" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(), new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clean up
                if (gchandle.IsAllocated)
                {
                    gchandle.Free();
                }
                if (!pSignerCertContext.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    Win32.CertFreeCertificateContext(pSignerCertContext);
                }
                if (!pSignerCertInfo.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pSignerCertInfo);
                }
                if (!hStore.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    Win32.CertCloseStore(hStore, Win32.CERT_CLOSE_STORE_FORCE_FLAG);
                }
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    stream.Close();
                }
                if (m_callbackFile != null)
                {
                    m_callbackFile.Close();
                }
                if (!hMsg.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    Win32.CryptMsgClose(hMsg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , When I try compile, I get the error The type or namespace 'Win32' could not be found, are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Hi BlueRaja, This effectively solves the decode, but now battling with the remove signature.

Comment: Ok, BlueRaja - you've helped me a lot, congrats on your bounty, essentially you no longer need to remove the signature, it happens during decode. Awesome! Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

I appear to have hit the post-length limit.  Here is the rest of the code from [the link](http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2010/04/09/how-to-call-cryptmsg-api-in-streaming-mode-c.aspx) mentioned above.

File win32.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace LargeCMS
{
    class Win32
    {
        #region "CONSTS"

        public const int X509_ASN_ENCODING = 0x00000001;
        public const int PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING = 0x00010000;
        public const int CMSG_SIGNED = 2;
        public const int CMSG_DETACHED_FLAG = 0x00000004;
        public const int AT_KEYEXCHANGE = 1;
        public const int AT_SIGNATURE = 2;
        public const String szOID_OIWSEC_sha1 = "1.3.14.3.2.26";
        public const int CMSG_CTRL_VERIFY_SIGNATURE = 1;
        public const int CMSG_CERT_PARAM = 12;
        public const int CMSG_SIGNER_CERT_INFO_PARAM = 7;
        public const int CERT_STORE_PROV_MSG = 1;
        public const int CERT_CLOSE_STORE_FORCE_FLAG = 1;

        #endregion

        #region "STRUCTS"

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER
        {
            public String pszObjId;
            BLOB Parameters;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CERT_ID
        {
            public int dwIdChoice;
            public BLOB IssuerSerialNumberOrKeyIdOrHashId;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CMSG_SIGNER_ENCODE_INFO
        {
            public int cbSize;
            public IntPtr pCertInfo;
            public IntPtr hCryptProvOrhNCryptKey;
            public int dwKeySpec;
            public CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER HashAlgorithm;
            public IntPtr pvHashAuxInfo;
            public int cAuthAttr;
            public IntPtr rgAuthAttr;
            public int cUnauthAttr;
            public IntPtr rgUnauthAttr;
            public CERT_ID                    SignerId;
            public CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER HashEncryptionAlgorithm;
            public IntPtr pvHashEncryptionAuxInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CERT_CONTEXT
        {
            public int dwCertEncodingType;
            public IntPtr pbCertEncoded;
            public int cbCertEncoded;
            public IntPtr pCertInfo;
            public IntPtr hCertStore;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct BLOB
        {
            public int cbData;
            public IntPtr pbData;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CMSG_SIGNED_ENCODE_INFO
        {
            public int cbSize;
            public int cSigners;
            public IntPtr rgSigners;
            public int cCertEncoded;
            public IntPtr rgCertEncoded;
            public int cCrlEncoded;
            public IntPtr rgCrlEncoded;
            public int cAttrCertEncoded;
            public IntPtr rgAttrCertEncoded;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CMSG_STREAM_INFO
        {
            public int cbContent;
            public StreamOutputCallbackDelegate pfnStreamOutput;
            public IntPtr pvArg;
        }

        #endregion

        #region "DELEGATES"

        public delegate Boolean StreamOutputCallbackDelegate(IntPtr pvArg, IntPtr pbData, int cbData, Boolean fFinal);

        #endregion

        #region "API"

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean CryptAcquireContext(
          ref IntPtr hProv,
          String pszContainer,
          String pszProvider,
          int dwProvType,
          int dwFlags
        );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr CryptMsgOpenToEncode(
            int dwMsgEncodingType,
            int dwFlags,
            int dwMsgType,
            ref CMSG_SIGNED_ENCODE_INFO pvMsgEncodeInfo,
            String pszInnerContentObjID,
            ref CMSG_STREAM_INFO pStreamInfo
        );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr CryptMsgOpenToDecode(
            int dwMsgEncodingType,
            int dwFlags,
            int dwMsgType,
            IntPtr hCryptProv,
            IntPtr pRecipientInfo,
            ref CMSG_STREAM_INFO pStreamInfo
        );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean CryptMsgClose(
            IntPtr hCryptMsg
        );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean CryptMsgUpdate(
            IntPtr hCryptMsg,
            Byte[] pbData,
            int cbData,
            Boolean fFinal
        );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean CryptMsgUpdate(
            IntPtr hCryptMsg,
            IntPtr pbData,
            int cbData,
            Boolean fFinal
        );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean CryptMsgGetParam(
            IntPtr hCryptMsg,
            int dwParamType,
            int dwIndex,
            IntPtr pvData,
            ref int pcbData
        );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean CryptMsgControl(
            IntPtr hCryptMsg,
            int dwFlags,
            int dwCtrlType,
            IntPtr pvCtrlPara
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean CryptReleaseContext(
            IntPtr hProv,
            int dwFlags
        );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr CertCreateCertificateContext(
            int dwCertEncodingType,
            IntPtr pbCertEncoded,
            int cbCertEncoded
        );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean CertFreeCertificateContext(
            IntPtr pCertContext
        );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr CertOpenStore(
            int lpszStoreProvider,
            int dwMsgAndCertEncodingType,
            IntPtr hCryptProv,
            int dwFlags,
            IntPtr pvPara
        );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr CertGetSubjectCertificateFromStore(
            IntPtr hCertStore,
            int dwCertEncodingType,
            IntPtr pCertId
        );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr CertCloseStore(
            IntPtr hCertStore,
            int dwFlags
        );

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this error on a file < 100 MB and only on Windows 7, it is probably due to a bug in Windows 7 64bit. I reported this to Microsoft two weeks ago, and received an email today confirming the bug and stating that a fix is undergoing internal testing and is very likely to be included in Win 7 SP1 due february 2011 (date not confirmed).

If you can't wait, the Win32/CryptMsg solution others have suggested seems to be the best workaround.

Update: Microsoft has today released an official fix, get it here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2480994
They have also confirmed that this fix will be included in SP2, not SP1.